# Template tag inside react jsx

Tags: meteor, reactjs

Im playing with meteor and reactjs and I would like to define a Template, inside a component, something like this:

```js
render() {
return (
  <div className="container">
    <template name="postsList">
      <ul>
        {this.renderPosts()}
      </ul>
    </template>
  </div>
); }
```

Meteor can't find it, and nothing gets rendered, can't we use the template tag inside jsx?

Comment: Perhaps something like this https://react-in-meteor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/react-template-helper/

Comment: @HenrikAndersson this was exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: There is a new link for react components in Meteor templates,
[here.](https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/blob/47504c7e87649ca5c6be7acb4c3ec57b02e66713/docs/react-template-helper.md)